# PyInstaller Secondary Import

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am building a PyQT5 application and bundling it with PyInstaller. The application is split into two parts: GUI.py and main.py. Upon dialog submission, GUI.py will call main.py.

However, the bundled executable could not resolve the main.py import.

```
# GUI.py

from main_file import main

### GUI STUFF ###
```

My spec file looks something like this.

```
a = Analysis(['GUI.py', 'main_file.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=collect_dynamic_libs("rtree"), 
             datas=collect_data_files('geopandas', subdir='datasets'),
             hiddenimports=hidden_imports, 
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=['hook.py'],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

How does PyInstaller import additional scripts beyond the executable's entry point? Is there something that needs to be specified within the .spec file? Should the import syntax be different? Or should I use the _MEIPASS resource path to import the other scripts?

Comment: Have you tried running pyinstaller normal?

Comment: As in without any spec files and just using the onefile/onedir flag? I have too many hidden imports and dependencies, so that is out of the question.

Comment: My understanding of PyInstaller goes as far as it will automatically scan and search for all needed libraries and include them.